# How can I write simple unit tests in jasmine to test if my firestore database data gets data and can write data to it?

Tags: angular, testing, google-cloud-firestore, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My website is build in Angular and it makes use of a firestore database. For this question I will simplify the situation. I have a service, called the `artist.service`, which handles all the crud operations for an artist. Multiple components make use of this `artist.service`. This is what the service looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Artist } from '../models/artist';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ArtistService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {}

  create(artist: Observable<Artist>) {
    return this.db.collection('/artists').add(artist);
  }

  getAll(): any {
    return this.db.collection('/artists');
  }

  getOne(artistId: string): AngularFirestoreDocument<Artist> {
    return this.db.doc('/artists/' + artistId);
  }

  update(artistId: string, artist: Observable<Artist>) {
    return this.db.doc('/artists/' + artistId).update(artist);
  }

  delete(artistId: string) {
    return this.db.doc('/artists/' + artistId).delete();
  }
}
```

I want to test if I am able to get data from each of these methods in different scenario's. This is why I want to make the tests in each of the components spec files (files used for testing).

The following code is for the `admin-artist` component. This is where artists get displayed in a table.

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  OnDestroy,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/internal/Subscription';
import { ArtistService } from '../../service/artist.service';

import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSort, Sort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { Artist } from 'src/app/models/artist';

@Component({
  selector: 'admin-artist',
  templateUrl: './admin-artist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-artist.component.css'],
})
export class AdminArtistComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  artists: Artist[];
  filteredArtists: Artist[];
  subscription: Subscription;

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['img', 'name', 'country', 'edit'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Artist>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private artistService: ArtistService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.artistService
      .getAll()
      .valueChanges({
        idField: 'key',
      })
      .subscribe((artists: any) => {
        this.filteredArtists = this.artists = artists.map((artist: any) => {
          return {
            name: artist['name'],
            country: artist['country'],
            imageUrl: artist['imageUrl'],
            key: artist['key'],
          };
        });
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Artist>(this.filteredArtists);
        this.initPaginatorAndSort();
      });
  }

  initPaginatorAndSort(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  filter(query: string) {
    this.filteredArtists = query
      ? this.artists.filter(
          (p) =>
            p.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) ||
            p.country.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
        )
      : this.artists;
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Artist>(this.filteredArtists);
    this.initPaginatorAndSort();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

This is the code for the form, which handles saving, updating and deleting. The file is called `artist-form`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, take } from 'rxjs';
import { Artist } from 'src/app/models/artist';
import { ArtistService } from '../../service/artist.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'artist-form',
  templateUrl: './artist-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./artist-form.component.css'],
})
export class ArtistFormComponent implements OnInit {
  artist: any = {};
  id: string;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private artistService: ArtistService
  ) {}

  save(artist: Observable<Artist>) {
    if (this.id) {
      this.artistService.update(this.id, artist);
    } else {
      this.artistService.create(artist);
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/artists']);
  }

  delete() {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this artist?')) return;
    this.artistService.delete(this.id);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/artists']);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (this.id) {
      this.artistService
        .getOne(this.id)
        .valueChanges({
          idField: 'key',
        })
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe((p) => (this.artist = p));
    }
  }
}
```

All of this code works. The issue comes when I want to test it using jasmine and karma. I want to make simple unit tests that make sure that each function works. I started with the getAll method, but quickly realized that the test always came back as SUCCEEDED. This is the test i wrote in the `admin-artist.spec` file:

```
import {
  ComponentFixture,
  inject,
  TestBed,
  tick,
  waitForAsync,
} from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AdminArtistComponent } from './admin-artist.component';
import { ArtistService } from '../../service/artist.service';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { of } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/of';

describe('AdminArtistComponent', () => {
  let component: AdminArtistComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AdminArtistComponent>;
  let service: ArtistService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AdminArtistComponent],
      providers: [ArtistService],
      imports: [
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFirestoreModule,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AdminArtistComponent);
    service = TestBed.inject(ArtistService);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should get all the music', waitForAsync(
    inject([ArtistService], (service: ArtistService) => {
      expect(service.getAll()).not.toBeUndefined;
    })
  ));
});
```

Can anyone help me with this? I just need a simple unit test for every method, but I dont know where to start.
If this question needs further explanation, let me know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you should either write a mock service, dummy value, or spy that will not make any API calls because it's not a good practice.

You can read a great explanation in Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#services-with-dependencies) with examples for your specific need.